# How to count users from Firebase with PHP (Laravel 5.8)

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to figure out how to count all registered users from the Firebase. I've only implemented the Firebase authentication and have not mannualy created a database.

I can't find a way to count or even get them from Firebase.

```php
$serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(config_path('path-to-file.json'));
$firebase = (new Factory())
    ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)
    ->create();
$database = $firebase->getDatabase();
```

I've got a connection with the code above.

Also I tried to use the auth helper like:

```php
$auth = $firebase->getAuth();
$users = $auth->listUsers($defaultMaxResults = 1000, $defaultBatchSize = 1000);
```

But the thing I only managed with this was getting the current user.

Anyone knows how to count all users / get them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi, maintainer of the [SDK you're using](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php) here :).

There is currently (as of 2019-08-29 and as far as I know) no way to directly get the number of registered users in a Firebase project except through iterating through all of them and counting them manually.

The fastest way to do this would be by using

```php
$users = $auth->listUsers();

$userCount = iterator_count($users);
```

We have to use `iterator_count` here because [`Auth::listUsers()`](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-management.html#list-users) returns a [`Generator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php) that behaves differently than the "usual" array: instead of fetching all the users at once, it will fetch the next batch only when we "need" it.

There are methods to convert an iterator to an array ([`iterator_to_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php)) and to count all items of an iterator ([`iterator_count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-count.php)), but under the hood, they will load *all* users into memory, which can become really expensive if you have thousands or hundreds of thousands of users.

For that reason, I would recommend not using `iterator_to_array()` but `foreach` when you want to work with the user records directly:

```php
foreach ($users as $user) {
    /** @var \Kreait\Firebase\Auth\UserRecord $user */
    echo $user->uid;
}
```

as well as using `iterator_count()` only sparingly and cache the result when you have it.

PS: Did you know that there's now a [Laravel Package for this SDK](https://github.com/kreait/laravel-firebase) as well?

Comment: Thanks for your response, going to try this out when I'm back from laraconEU :)

Comment: Worked, for now I leave it in, but if it become too heavy, I'll just pull out this widget. It is a nice to have widget.