# How to connect firebase authentication with laravel

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to firebase and laravel. I want to connect laravel with firebase. 
I don't know where to start  but I have read some articles in websites.

[laravel-firebase-auth-medium](https://medium.com/@morrislaptop/laravel-firebase-auth-cff892b116a2)

But it doesn't have a clear documentation . 
I also tried to implement it via the react js . But 
How can I use the authenticated users from firebase as `Auth::users()` in `laravel`?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a great place to recommend off-site resources. But this gives some promising results: https://www.google.com/search?q=use+firebase+for+laravel. Give them a try. And if you can't get any of them to work, post back with the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also see this previous question that uses `listUsers` and has an answer from the library's author: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57698602/how-to-count-users-from-firebase-with-php-laravel-5-8

Answer (score 0):

**Firebase Authentication Package for Laravel**

> Description

Firebase Authentication package Baked for Laravel and currently supports Facebook and Google Login. Other methods will be added shortly.

> https://github.com/kkcodes/laravel-firebase-auth